# Show icons or badges under title on product archives/category pages

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, archives

I have a website that sells gaming related stuff, i need to show some buffs as icons/small images under every product below the product image, on the archive/category page, apparently there is no such option nor plugin on the internet that can help me (i would like to be corrected on this please)

So i am trying to work around this on my own, i have very basic coding knowledge.

They way i am trying to do it is by:

1. These icons are common to the products but their combinations are unique per 
   product, to make it easy i made them as attributes so i can easily assign 
   them per product.
2. Installed the variation swatches for woocommerce plugin so
   attributes can have there own images
3. Made an attribute and made its sub-attributes as my icons and attached 
   images.
4. All my products are simple downloadable products so variation
   swatches for woocommerce is of no help as it only works for variable
   products, but it gave attributes their own images.
5. Currently i can output the values on attributes on my product cat/archive page with the following 
   code but not images as i have no idea how to call them.

I can display the attributes and there values using the following code

```
<?php 

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'loop_attributes', 20 );
function loop_attributes() {
global $product;

if( ! is_object( $product ) ) { 
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
}

$win_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_wins');
$hour_val  = $product->get_attribute('pa_hours');
$badge_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_badges');
$token_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_token');

echo '<img src="' . $token_val . '" class="aligncenter" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" />';

echo '<span class="attrs1"><i style="color:#1c7e5a;" class="fas fa-trophy"></i> Wins:</span>'.'<span 
class="attrs2"> '.$win_val.' </span>';
echo '<span class="attrs1"><i style="color:#1c7e5a;" class="fas fa-hourglass"></i> Hours: 
</span>'.'<span class="attrs2"> '.$hour_val.' </span>';
echo '<span class="attrs1"><i style="color:#1c7e5a;" class="fas fa-ribbon"></i> Badges: 
</span>'.'<span class="attrs2"> '.$badge_val.' </span>';
 }

add_filter( 'woocommerce_hide_invisible_variations', '__return_false' );

 ?>
```

The code above shows the corresponding attribute name and their values on the product cat/archive page,

The attribute pa_token has images attached to their values,

I want the pa_token to output its attached images instead of values, in the below example the code for pa_token is a representation of what i want its not a working code,

```
echo '<img src="' . $token_val . '" class="aligncenter" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" />';
```

I need advice if this is a good approach or is there already a solution for this ? If not then how can i go about calling the images attached to the attributes!

**Update 1:**

When i put this code

```
function loop_attributes() {
global $product;

if( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($product->get_attributes(), 1), '</pre>';

$token_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_token');

echo '<pre>', print_r($token_val, 1), '</pre>'; 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'loop_attributes', 10, 0 );
```

I get the following output

```
Array
( 

[pa_token] => WC_Product_Attribute Object
    (
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9
                [name] => pa_token
                [options] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 210
                        [1] => 211
                    )

                [position] => 6
                [visible] => 1
                [variation] => 
            )

    )

 )

 a, bb
```

a, bb are the sub attributes/values that have images attached to them

pa_token-> a - Icon 1, bb - Icon 2

**Update 2:**

So if i do the following code

```
var_dump( get_term_meta( 210 ) );
```

I get the following output, looks like we are heading to the right path

```
array(6) { ["order_pa_token"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } 
["product_attribute_image"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "12706" } 
["image_size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "thumbnail" } ["show_tooltip"]=> 
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "text" } ["tooltip_text"]=> array(1) { [0]=> 
string(3) "aaa" } ["tooltip_image"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

I guess we have the meta now, now what should be the relevant code to only output the images with there tooltips on the category/archive page ?

**Update 3:**

By updating the code to :

```
function loop_attributes() {
    global $product;

    if( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    // Get Product Variations - WC_Product_Attribute Object
    $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    // Not empty, contains values
    if ( !empty( $product_attributes ) ) {

        foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute ) {
            // Get options
            $attribute_options = $product_attribute->get_options();

            // Not empty, contains values
            if ( !empty( $attribute_options ) ) {

                foreach ($attribute_options as $key => $attribute_option ) {
                    // WP_Term Object
                    $term = get_term($attribute_option); // <-- your term ID

                    echo '<pre>', print_r($term, 1), '</pre>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'loop_attributes', 10, 0 );
```

i get the below output

```
<pre>
WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 210
    [name] => a
    [slug] => aa
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 210
    [taxonomy] => pa_token
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 2
    [filter] => raw
)
</pre>

<pre>
WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 211
    [name] => bb
    [slug] => bb
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 211
    [taxonomy] => pa_token
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 2
    [filter] => raw
)
</pre>
```

**Update 4:**

So i was not able to solve my problem earlier, then i switched the plugin to Category and Taxonomy Image by Aftab Hussain and used the following code to call images on the category/archive loop page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 
'attribute_img_loop', 20 );
 function attribute_img_loop() {
 global $product;

// Check that we got the instance of the WC_Product object, to be sure (can 
be removed)
if( ! is_object( $product ) ) { 
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
}

$token_imgs = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'pa_token');

foreach ( (array) $token_imgs as $token_img ) {
$terms = $token_img->term_id;

    $meta_image = get_wp_term_image($terms); 
echo '<ul><li><img src="' . $meta_image . '" class="tokenimg" " /></li> 
</ul>';
}
}
```

pa_token is my attribute with sub attributes that have images

foreach loop is used to output all the sub attributes used per product, otherwise it will output only the first result.

(array) inside foreach loop is used to not return anything if the value is null, otherwise all the other products with no attributes get an ugly php debug error on the main page, let me know if there is a non hack way to handle this.

Thanks for your help guys for giving me the right direction.

Comment: Instead of the variation swatches plugin, why not use ACF? It'd be easier for you to get the term icon and other term metadata.

Comment: well i tried but by default we don't have images for attributes in woocommerce, and with ACF i will need to define all 30-40 icons per product, i solely used variation swatches as it gives me the option to set images for attributes, i could not get that option with custom hooks i found on the internet, secondly this website will be operated by someone who has no idea about these things, so i am trying to make it easier on the users end. defining these icons through attributes seems to be the easiest as the user can easily select the required icons per product thanks :)

Comment: Or maybe i am overlooking something obvious and easy :@

Comment: Alright then, but as I already pointed, the attribute images are likely saved as term meta, so based on the dump output in the question, you could do `var_dump( get_term_meta( 210 ) );` to find the relevant meta. But if you downloaded a plugin from WordPress.org, then you could ask on the plugin's support forums - someone experienced with the plugin, if not the author, might be able to help you.

Comment: I just edited my main question with the output, for  `var_dump( get_term_meta( 210 ) );` @SallyCJ

Comment: So I don't know that `tooltip_image` is or does, but you can try using the value of the meta `product_attribute_image`, which in the question is `12706` and which looks like an attachment ID. And if it is, you can use functions like [`wp_get_attachment_image_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) for retrieving the URL for an attachment/image. But once again, try asking on the plugin support forums/site - there might be a plugin-specific or an easier way to retrieve/display the data you want.

Comment: hey thanks for the input, yes i figured, but my problem is i don't know the code to fetch and loop all those images in an archive, sorry for being so persistent and dumb! :D i asked the plugin author, i am still to get a response, but i doubt it

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to help you further, but I couldn't reply earlier on. Anyway, I suggest you to undo the edit to your question (roll back to the last revision) and instead, post the solution as an answer and accept it later. :) All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was not able to solve my problem earlier, then I switched the plugin to "[Category and Taxonomy Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-image/)" (by Aftab Hussain) and used the following code to display the icons on category/archive pages:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'attribute_img_loop', 20 );
function attribute_img_loop() {
    global $product;

    // Check that we got the instance of the WC_Product object, to be sure (can
    // be removed)
    if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    }

    $token_imgs = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'pa_token' );

    foreach ( (array) $token_imgs as $token_img ) {
        $terms = $token_img->term_id;

        $meta_image = get_wp_term_image( $terms );
        echo '<ul><li><img src="' . $meta_image . '" class="tokenimg" /></li></ul>';
    }
}
```

- `pa_token` is my attribute with sub-attributes/terms that have images.
- `foreach` loop is used to output all the sub-attributes used per product, otherwise it will output only the first result.
- `(array)` inside the `foreach` loop is used to not return anything if the value is null, otherwise all the other products with no attributes get an ugly PHP debug error on the main page.

Thanks for your help guys, for giving me the right direction.

**Notes from Sally:**

1. I'd just remove the `$product` since you don't really need it there because you used `get_the_terms()` and not a WooCommerce-specific function for getting the `pa_token` terms.
2. I don't recommend the `(array) $token_imgs`. Instead, make sure the `$token_imgs` is not a `WP_Error` instance and that it's not an empty array.
3. Instead of multiple `ul` (`<ul><li></li></ul> <ul><li></li></ul> <ul><li></li></ul>...`), I'd use multiple `li` (`<ul><li></li> <li></li> <li></li>...</ul>`). :)

So my code would be:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'attribute_img_loop', 20 );
function attribute_img_loop() {
    $token_imgs = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'pa_token' );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $token_imgs ) && ! empty( $token_imgs ) ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $token_imgs as $term ) {
            $meta_image = get_wp_term_image( $term->term_id );
            echo '<li><img src="' . $meta_image . '" class="tokenimg" /></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind I revised the answer and hopefully the notes help you. :) Cheers!

Comment: Not at all this is awesome and works as i needed in a much cleaner way! thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the plugin you use for adding images. You can run the following code, this will give you more information about where to find the path to the image.

```php
function loop_attributes() {
    global $product;

    if( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    // Get Product Variations - WC_Product_Attribute Object
    $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    // Not empty, contains values
    if ( !empty( $product_attributes ) ) {

        foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute ) {
            // Get options
            $attribute_options = $product_attribute->get_options();

            // Not empty, contains values
            if ( !empty( $attribute_options ) ) {

                foreach ($attribute_options as $key => $attribute_option ) {
                    // WP_Term Object
                    $term = get_term($attribute_option); // <-- your term ID

                    echo '<pre>', print_r($term, 1), '</pre>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'loop_attributes', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the code, i have edited my main question with the output

Comment: Take a look at the progress :) @7uc1f3r

Comment: I have adjusted my answer, can you continue with that?

Comment: I have updated my original question with your updated code! i still have no clue, sorry i am not good with advanced coding and fetching data from nested arrays :(